# Update data codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

The updated data still doesn't change. The possibility for an error is in the ubahTypeBarang function.
I have tried to find a solution, but still can't update the changed data

**This models**

```
public function ubahTypeBarang ()
{
    $data = [
        "barang_kode"=> $this->input->post('barang_kode', true),
        "type_id"=> $this->input->post('type_id', true),
        "barang_nama"=> $this->input->post('barang_nama', true),
    ];

    $this->db->where('barang_id', $this->input->post('barang_id'));
    $this->db->update('barang', $data);

}
```

**This view**

```
<div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                <label for="kode">Kode</label>
                                <input type="text" name="barang_kode" class="form-control text-uppercase" id="barang_kode" value="<?= $barang["barang_kode"]; ?>">
                                <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('kode') ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                <label for="type">Type</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="type_id" name="type_id">
                                    <?php foreach($type as $types) : ?>
                                        <?php if( $types->type_id == $barang['type_id']) : ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $types->type_id ?>" selected><?php echo $types->type_nama ?></option>
                                        <?php else : ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $types->type_id ?>"><?php echo $types->type_nama ?></option>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </select>
                                <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('type') ?></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label for="nama">Nama Barang</label>
                                <input type="text" name="barang_nama" class="form-control text-capitalize" id="barang_nama" value="<?= $barang["barang_nama"]; ?>">
                                <small class="form-text text-danger"><?= form_error('nama') ?></small>
                            </div>
                        </div>

        <button type="submit" name="tambah" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Tambah Data</button>
```

Comment: Are you even getting any values in the $_REQUEST array? can you post the output of var_dump($this->input->post()) ?

Comment: Are you sure that `barang_id` input is set up properly? or not empty?

Comment: yes I have got the value from barang_id

Comment: for barang_id input is correct

Comment: I only take the value from barang_id for updates

Comment: maybe the error is in the value of type_id @HastaDhana

Comment: On your `ubahTypeBarang` function, add a `print_r($_POST);`, what is the output of it?

Comment: I don't see any field that is sending the barang_id. Is there more to the form/html that you are not showing?

Comment: The problem has been resolved, thank's man @HastaDhana